# Debian и Ubuntu не доступны через vlan

Tags: linux, debian, vlan

Настроены vlan'ы на обоих машинах стандартным методом через vconfig

Это с одной машины

```
cat /proc/net/vlan/config
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
eth0.11        | 11  | eth0
```

Это с другой

```
cat /proc/net/vlan/config 
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
eth2.11        | 11  | eth2
```

Находятся в прямой видимости, соединены через пару умных коммутаторов. На обоих vlan'овских интерфейсах адреса из одной подсети. Хосты друг друга не видят. Куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На паре умных коммутаторах нужно обязательно прописать этот VLAN на тех портах, к которым подключены машины. Порты должны отдавать тегированный трафик на эти порты (т.н. TRUNK). Кроме того - на порты соединения коммутаторов тоже должен быть накинут этот VLAN.

Обратите внимание, что если к порту, к которому подключены обсуждаемые машины, подключены ещё какие-то устройства — у них сеть ляжет после включения порта в TRUNK.

Для более детального обсуждения нужна схема сети с указанием накинутых VLAN`ов, режимов портов и подключенными устройствами.

Пишите, обсудим, поможем!

Comment: @Дмитрий, если есть возможность соединить машины одним кабелем - попробуйте. Это снимет подозрение с ОС и укажет на ненастроенную сеть на коммутаторах.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, так и сделал. Как итог - всё взлетело. Дело в коммутаторах, требуется перенастройка.

Comment: Думаю этот вопрос исчерпан. Если потребуется помощь в настройке, стоит задать вопрос с описанием конфигураций портов и картой сети.

Comment: @GrayHoax, с vlan столкнулся второй раз, в первый всё было на "мыльницах" сделано, вот и завелось с первого тычка. Знаю, что мои коммутаторы поддерживают vlan и еже с ним, но не думал, что по умолчанию они фильтруют маркированные пакеты. Езё раз спасибо! Будут вопросы - обращусь.

Comment: В продолжение темы. Вопрос по настройке коммутаторов HP и 3Com http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441829/3com-2920-hp-v1910-vlan