# 3Com-2920 (HP-v1910), VLAN

Tags: сеть, hp, vlan, коммутатор

Есть несколько коммутаторов 3Com и на их базе HP, а конкретно 3com 2920 и HP v1910. В коммутатор-1 вставлен шнурок от провайдера, необходимо трафик от провайдера изолировано прокинуть через несколько коммутаторов на определённый порт в последнем коммутаторе и дальше через определённый порт в сервер таким. Ко всему прочему через все коммутаторы должны пропускаться нетегированый трафик.
Схема следующая

```
Провайдер -- 1 порт Коммутатор-1 16порт -- 1 порт Коммутатор-2 16 порт -- 1 порт Коммутатор-3 16 порт -- Сервер
```

Это для примера.
Что я сделал.

```
На Коммутаторе-1:
1 порт выставил в Acces и назначил vlan 77
16 порт выставил в Trunk и назначил Tagged 77, Untagged 1

На Коммутаторе-2:
1 и 16 порт по аналогии с 16м портом на Коммутаторе-1

На Коммутаторе-3:
1 порт выставил в Trunk и назначил Tagged 77, Untagged 1
16 порт выставил в Acces и назначил vlan 77
```

Сервер (пока это тестовый ноут) не видит провайдера.

Что я сделал не так? Скажите куда посмотреть

Comment: А на сетевой карте ноута пробовали vlan_id в 77 выставлять?

Comment: На ноуте сетевуха не позволяет прописать vlan, по этой причине она должна пропускать тегированые пакеты. Wireshark'ом сниферил, но ни одного тегированого пакета.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил сам. Неверно были соединены между собой коммутаторы. Проверяйте всегда всё хорошо.